# Unable to remove element from ArrayObject

Tags: php

I have a simple class which extends ArrayObject. It looks like so:

```
class SimpleCollection extends ArrayObject
{

    public function __construct($arr = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($arr, ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);   
    }


    public function contains($value)   
    {
        return in_array($value, $this->getArrayCopy());        
    }


    public function remove($vertex)
    {
        unset($this[$vertex]);     
    }
}
```

Its constructor and `contains` method work as expected. But `remove` method does not work:

```
$arr = new SimpleCollection(['b']);

$arr->remove('b');

echo $arr->contains('b');
```

The last command prints `true`, even though I tried to remove an element form my object. What is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Comment: And by the way, if there is a better way to check whether my simple collection contains an element (without constructing a copy of array), it would be great to know.

Comment: plz provide the code for `$this->getArrayCopy()`

Comment: `getArrayCopy` is a method implemented in `ArrayObject`. It is not a custom method.

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting? Because when executing your code it throws an error at `unset()` for `b` (`E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: b`) which means that you are not accessing the actual ArrayObject when trying to unset the `b` index.

Comment: @Tom Udding. I have not done that. But judging by the result this construct does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730024/unable-to-remove-element-from-arrayobject/48730101#comment84459142_48730024) it throws an error at the `unset()` function because index `b` is not defined. If we take a look at `var_dump($arr)` this makes sense:

```
object(SimpleCollection)#1 (1) { 
    ["storage":"ArrayObject":private] => array(1) {
        [0]=> string(1) "b" 
    }
}
```

When you do `$arr = new SimpleCollection(['b']);` it doesn't make `b` the index, it makes `b` the value with an index of `0`.

Which also makes sense because `['b']` is

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "b"
}
```

---

To get the desired result you'll have to change `['b']` to something like `['b' => 'something']`. Then the `remove()` function will work.